# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector of specific tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I would like to know if exist the analytical solution for the eingenvalue
to the following tridiagonal matrix:

$A_{i,i}=i$ for $i=1,2,...,N$,

$A_{i,i+1}=A_{i+1,i}=1$

$$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 &0 &...&0&0\\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 0&...&0&0\\
    0 & 1 & 3 &1&...&0&0\\
    0&0&1&4&1&...&0&\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots 
    \end{matrix}\right)
$$

For simplicity, elements can assume small values ​​of type:
$A_{i,i+1}=A_{i+1,i}=\epsilon$ or $A_{i,i}=1+i\epsilon$ .

I solved the homogeneous case with a recurrence relation, but in this case I have a complicated recurrence relation. If anyone has an idea how I can work with the eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors of this matrix, I would be very grateful.